# How to get Cxfrs:server input and output types

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse, cxfrs

I'm trying to build Response according to the output type specified in cxfrs:server service class.

`@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({"application/xml"})`

How can I get the Consumes type and Produces type using cxf interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information from [OperationResourceInfo](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/model/OperationResourceInfo.html) The interceptor should looks like this

```
public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    public MyInterceptor () {
        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
       OperationResourceInfo m = message.getExchange().get(OperationResourceInfo.class);
       List<javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType> consumes = m.getConsumeTypes();
       List<javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType> produces = m.getProduceTypes();
    }

    public void handleFault(Message messageParam) {
        //Invoked when interceptor fails
    }
}
```

Remember to add a `in` or `out` interceptor to your endpoint